# The entity "copy" was referenced, but not declared in jspx

Tags: jspx

I want to use copyright symbol in jspx, but it is not allowing me to use © . It is throwing me an error.

The entity "copy" was referenced, but not declared.

I googled it out and found that i need to modify escapeMode . But I do not know where I should change it.

Or anyone has the solution, please let me know.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may need to find the  section of your template and add the entity declaration.

Here's an example with a few common entities:

```
<!DOCTYPE html [
<!ENTITY nbsp "&#160;">  
<!ENTITY copy "&#169;"> 
<!ENTITY bull "&#8226;"> ]>
```

[Here is a list of the entities in HTML4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/entities.html)